# Adding extra rows with labels by typing in a entry box in tkinter / Python without a button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I would like to see new labels and entry boxes apear after I typed a number in an already existing entry box without having to use a button.

My while loop is probably also wrong. But I hope you get my intention. This is all new to me.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

label_amount = tk.Label(text="Amount")
label_amount.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry_amount = tk.Entry()
entry_amount.grid(row=0, column=1)

# TODO - create a label and entry * amount entered
# i = 1
# while i < int(entry_amount.get()):
#     label_container = tk.Label(text=f"Container {i}")
#     label_container.grid(row=i, column=1)
#
#     entry_container = tk.Entry()
#     entry_container.grid(row=i, column=2)
#
#     i = i + 1

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can bind `<Return>` (*Enter* key) to a callback and create the input number of those labels and entries inside the callback.  It is better to create those labels and entries inside a frame so that you can destroy them easier before creating new ones.

Answer (score 1):

It worked.
This is the final code.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()


def function(event):
    # create a label and entry * amount entered
    if entry_amount.get() == "":
        return
    else:
        i = 1
        while i <= int(entry_amount.get()):
            label_container = tk.Label(text=f"Container {i}")
            label_container.grid(row=i, column=1)

            entry_container = tk.Entry()
            entry_container.grid(row=i, column=2)

            i = i + 1


window.bind("<Return>", function)

label_amount = tk.Label(text="Amount")
label_amount.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry_amount = tk.Entry()
entry_amount.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_amount.focus()

window.mainloop()
```